# trouble with oidentd on CentOS 6.3

Tags: centos, configuration, vps, centos6, linux

I'm having a weird problem with the oident daemon on my VPS.
When I try running it, I keep getting this error:

> [root@ldvps ~]# oidentd
>   [line 4] This construct is valid only for user configuration files
>   Error reading configuration file

I also made sure that it reads the correct oidentd.conf from /etc/oidentd.conf by typing

> oidentd -c /etc/oidentd.conf

but I get the same error.

Here's my oidentd.conf file:

```
# Configuration for oidentd
# see oidentd.conf(5)
#

default {
        default {
                allow spoof
                allow spoof_all
                allow spoof_privport
                allow random
                allow random_numeric
                allow numeric
                allow hide
        }
}
```

There's either something I'm not doing right or there's really a problem with the oidentd.
Any help or other suggestions would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `/etc/oidentd.conf` should look like the following:

```
default {
    default {
        allow spoof
        deny spoof_all
        deny spoof_privport
        allow random_numeric
        allow numeric
        allow hide
    }
}

user root {
    default {
        force reply "UNKNOWN"
    }
}

user username {
    default {
        allow spoof
        allow spoof_all
        allow spoof_privport
    }
}
```

You could define per user configuration. Issue the following

`vi ~/.oidentd.conf`

```
global { reply "nickname" }
to irc.freenode.net { reply "freenode" }
```

Comment: now I got a syntax error at line 1...

Comment: Please provide more information. You either have a typo or have not run oidentd correctly. Provide the full error so could debug it easily.

Comment: so I updated /etc/oidentd.conf with the one you provided and and then typed this onto ssh: oidentd -c /etc/oidentd.conf

here's the log:
[root@ldvps ~]# oidentd -c /etc/oidentd.conf
[line 1] syntax error
Error reading configuration file

Comment: first line is the `default` word. Here starts the definition of the file. This cannot be a syntax error. How did you install oidentd? Did you use rpm/yum  or installed it from source and if so, what flags did you use during the compilation time?

Comment: I used yum. -> yum install oidentd

Comment: Did you change file permissions? does your file contain ^M characters ?  You can find this out by typing `cat -A /etc/oidentd.conf`

Comment: oh.. it seems to have ^M characters. how do I remove that?

Comment: `tr -d '\r' <oidentd.conf>copy_oidentd.conf; mv copy_oidentd.conf oidentd.conf`